# Connect to remote UDP multicast service

Tags: c++, networking, udp, multicast, ace

How to connect to remote udp multicast if I have an IP address where the service resided (say `70.70.70.70`), the multicast group to connect (say `224.25.25.25`) and port (say `2020`)?

I use ACE framework and in the sniffer I see that ACE sends IGMP packet to `224.0.0.2`, in order to join a group, but my home router (checkpoint) doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Routers are rarely made and configured to support resending multicast packets to other networks. In other words, multicasts usually work only via one subnet. In most cases multicast over internet is based on establishing TCP connection between peers and sending messages using some transport on top of that TCP connection (look for information about message-oriented middleware).

If you have some particular server, which welcomes you to join to it's multicast, maybe you can provide more details about what this server offers and what it needs to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen multicast work on local subnets, so a good first test is to setup the multicast service on a local computer, and see if that works. I've never had success getting multicast to work for remote services, only places where all routers can be controlled, like behind a corporate firewall. Seems like it should work, and I'd like to see examples of the general case working...

Answer (score 0):

You need IP tunneling, a basic VPN service would work but you might need multicast routing above that depending upon your configuration.  Wander over to serverfault or superuser for more help.

Comment: Hey Steve-o! I implemented this, but am not sure of how to connect to the machine on the otherside of the tunnel. Would you mind checking out my question here? http://serverfault.com/questions/770773/joining-a-udp-multicast-through-a-server-on-the-other-side-of-the-tunnel 

Thanks so much Steve-o

Answer (score 0):

> I have an IP address where the service
>   resided (say 70.70.70.70)

You don't need that.

> the multicast group to connect (say
>   224.25.25.25)

You need that. You need to issue the join-group operation using that address.

> and port (say 2020)?

You should have a UDP socket listening at that port.